# wiring a kitchen under counter oven - is this setup correct?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, oven, fire-hazard

**Here are the oven wiring specs:**

POWER / RATINGS

- Amp Rating at 208V:  **20**
- Amp Rating at 240V:  **20**
- Bake Wattage:        **2100W**
- Broiler Wattage:     **3600W**
- Convection Wattage:  **2500W**
- KW Rating at 208V:   **2.8**
- KW Rating at 240V:   **3.8**

**I've installed a 12/3 home run**

**And this is the breaker than I intend to purchase:**

[https://www.amazon.com/Square-Schneider-Electric-QO220CP-Two-Pole/dp/B007IAZCQM/ref=sr_1_32?ie=UTF8&qid=1529384864&sr=8-32&keywords=square+d+breakers+20+amp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007IAZCQM)

Other than stepping up the wire gauge, Is this an acceptable setup? I don't want to burn the house down.

Comment: Your electrical panel is a QO, correct?  (If you're not sure, simply post photos of the panel and label and we can figure it out from there)

Comment: the breaker is the right brand-match for the panel. https://imgur.com/a/Qvsh90N

I just want to know if the breaker, plus wiring, plus power ratings are a match - I'm 99.9% sure they are, but want to consult the internet first ;-)

Comment: You probably won't get in too much trouble with QO vs Homeline, but for other's benefit: other brands can be tricky, and you need to note the breaker series.  It's about fit, not brand.  Counterexample,  QO panels could use Siemens QD, that's "Queue Dee", (though it kinda looks like QO doesn't it, heh) since they are made *and UL listed* specifically for Square D QO panels only.

Comment: you are correct!!!! I didn't even see the QO - vs HOME branding on these! I'll find a 20amp breaker for the Homeline series! THANK YOU!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks well researched and complete to me.  The wire is perfect. Everything looks right.

The only thing that bugs me is opportunity cost: some building codes require you fit a 40A or 50A cable for the common/standard electric range/oven. Deluxe homes even like to see that and a 30A run for a separate dual oven.  So if it's easy now and won't be easy later, my inclination would be to throw a 10/3 and 6/3 in the wall.

Comment: Good point and I thought about upgrading the wiring. The house was built in 1942 and in San Francisco. The kitchen is directly above the garage where the panel is at. My thoughts are that if the next person that owns this house wants to upgrade, they will only need to remove a patch of drywall downstairs to fish a new home-run. This kitchen is purpose built for me - electric for the oven - gas for the cooktop. So, for now, I'll leave it as is and go with what I need for myself only.

Comment: 1942 in San Fran? So new housing stock, then :)  Borrow a trick from the Victorian houses and put adorable little hatches in maintenance locations. Makes servicing our tub faucet embarrassingly easy.

Comment: I did just that in the garage below the tub! The wife ensures that i'll never have to service it - super long showers.

Comment: With gas a 40/50 amp is not required in the states I have worked.

Answer (score 0):

### Right make, wrong series

What caught you out here is that Square-D makes *two* lines of breakers: the 3/4" wide QO (their "premium" line), and the 1" wide HomeLine (HOM for short, and their "builder grade" line).  The breaker you link in your question is the former, but your panel is the latter, so you need a HOM220 instead of the QO220 you linked.

The 12/3 is adequate wire, although Harper's suggestion of fatter wire would not have been at all out of place, either.

Comment: and you are correct too! I didn't even notice the QO vs HOME branding. The wife just grabbed the right one from Lowes. I'll leave the wire for now as the kitchen is purpose built for myself at the moment. Someone else down the line might want to re-do it, but that's their problem :-)